# Simplifying ${n \choose k} 2^k (n-k)_k$, where $(n)_i$ is the falling factorial

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

> Is there a different way of writing
> $${n \choose k} 2^k (n-k)_k$$
> where $(n)_i = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-i+1)$ is the falling factorial?

One source says $$\frac{n!}{k!(k-1)!}2^k$$
and another says it is actually
$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-2k)!}2^k$$

Which one has the correct denominator? I guess my main problem is seeing what $(n-k)_k$ translates to.

Comment: There are several ways you can improve your post.  You refer to "one source" and "another" without identifying; surely it cannot be difficult to cite your sources.  You could present your own work in simplifying this expression, or at least explain why simplifying it became of interest to you.  Finally you could show Readers that by choosing some smallish values, say $n=3,k=1$, the two expression do give different results.  It follows that at most one of those expressions is correct, and if all you want is a correct expression, you could focus on proving that one.

Answer (score 2):

You said your main problem is "seeing", I hope this helps:

$$ \begin{aligned}
(n-k)_k &= (n-k) \cdots (n-k-k+1) \\
&= \frac{\overbrace{(n-k) \cdots (n-k-k+1)(n-k-k)\cdots 2 \cdot 1}^{(n-k)!}}{\phantom{(n-k) \cdots (n-k-k+1)}\underbrace{(n-k-k)\cdots 2 \cdot 1}_{(n-2k)!}} \\
&= \frac{(n-k)!}{(n-2k)!}
\end{aligned}$$

---

$$ \require{cancel} \binom{n}{k} (n-k)_k = \frac{n!}{k!\cancel{(n-k)!}}\cdot \frac{\cancel{(n-k)!}}{(n-2k)!} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-2k)!} $$

Answer (score 1):

Well your expression is equal to $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}2^k\underbrace{(n-k)\cdot...\cdot(n-2k+1)}_{=(n-k)_k}$ so the first terms in the denominator cancel out and you get that this is equal to $\frac{n!}{k!(n-2k)!}$. But note that for this to work $k$ has to be smaller than $\frac{n+1}{2}$.

Does this help?